# Issue with iphone sdk 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

Probably a silly question. When running my project on the Device in the debug mode I get a lot of warnings al having the following string:

> warning: Unable to read symbols for
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1
>   (8C148a)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/

I think its due to the space between "4.2.1" and "(8C148a)". How can i get rid of it? It must be a setting somewhere in Xcode.

I dont have these warnings on the simulator.

thanks in advance, Christian

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had this issue with 4.2.1 (8C148a), which I believe is caused by differing DeviceSupport files on the phone and in XCode. I tried many things, but eventually resolved it by deleting this folder:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/

After this I plugged in my iOS device and was asked to connect and restore the symbol files from the device, and it worked normally again.

Comment: This did not work for me.  I renamed the folder and then plugged in my iPhone4. Ran in debug and it still comes up with the warning.

Comment: You have to delete it.  Xcode and symbolicating script will keep finding it (probably via Spotlight).  I used the symbolicating script with verbose option and noticed it referencing the folder after I had moved it to the desktop.)

Comment: I had this issue with Xcode 4.3. I think as long as you quit Xcode in advance, you can get away with a rename.

Comment: Every time I try this, even after restarting Xcode and rebooting/restarting, it never works. :\

Answer (score 38):

I was getting:

warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).

Version 4.2.1 does not include 'info/dns.so'. At least that was the case for me. However, it does exist in the 4.2 directory and is pointed to by the /DeviceSupport/*Latest* shortcut. I simply copy-pasted 'info/dns.so' to where the debugger was looking for it and that seemed to fix the warning.

Comment: This is what I had to do to get it to work as well. Thanks for the info!

Comment: thanks, i copied it, which solved that error...but xcode is still buggy as hell

Comment: This worked for me. Had to also do this to resolve this error: `warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib`

Comment: @Brennon Bortz: I'm facing the same problem, except that I can't find a copy of libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib anywhere on my mac.

Comment: I totally forgot about this post. It's nearly 8 months later and the same problem started happening again in Xcode 4.  I remembered solving it before but I couldn't remember how.  Then I found this LOL! and it worked like a charm :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you plug an iOS device (iPad) with a slightly newer OS than the the ones in the SDK, a button to download new symbols should appear in the Organizer window of Xcode.  Hit it and wait.

Comment: I got that message when I plugged in my iPad but not when I plugged in iPhone with 4.2.1 after.  Now I can debug on my iPad but get device support warnings and crash on my iPhone.

Comment: The crash is my code problem but even after deleting /4.2.1 (8C134)/ and Organizer asking to downlod symbols I still get  warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).  if Figure out more I'll start new question.

Comment: thats exactly the last warning I still have. I read somewhere that it is supposed to be harmless. A can't find any problems neither. We will see. I just sent an update to apple with this warning still present.

Comment: The symbols for this: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen errors like that when my device wasn't on the same version as what I was building for. Are you sure you're not on a 4.2 beta?

Comment: i checked but i got the most recent sdk that is "final". Then i updated my phone via itunes. But i am reinstalling the sdk right now

Answer (score 1):

I don't think 8C148a is "final"; final builds numbers never seem to end in a letter (my phone is reporting "4.2.1 (8C148)"). I haven't debugged apps on it yet (I got bored waiting for it to extract symbols and went home).

4.2 GM was 8C134, so you're certainly running newer software, but something somewhere is getting the build number wrong.

But I digress.

---

What directories are in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport? If "4.2.1 (8C148a)" doesn't exist but "4.2.1" does, you might have luck doing something like this in Terminal:

```
cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
ln -s "4.2.1" "4.2.1 (8C134a)"
```

Equivalently, if "4.2.1 (8C148)" exists, do something like this instead:

```
ln -s "4.2.1 (8C148)" "4.2.1 (8C148a)"
```

You can generally use this trick to get Xcode to talk to a beta device without installing a beta SDK; this is useful if your company has some people running the beta (for testing purposes) and other people on the latest "final" (for release purposes).

Comment: Thanks, that helped.  I just deleted one of the last folders that was giving me conflicts and re-plugged my iphone in. It updated the broken symbols.

Answer (score 0):

There's a mismatch at the moment, where the released version of 4.2.1 is ahead of the SDK version 4.2

@Khrob's comment fixed it for me though!

Answer (score 0):

Until they provide a solid SDK, a cool workaround is to :

1 - select the Executable ( In 'Executables' in the project browser ),

2 - get info and turn off "Break on Debugger() and DebugStr()"*

Cheers, and best wishes for 2011.

T

This does not disable NSLog.

Answer (score 0):

I have 4.2.1 on an iPhone 3G and Xcode 3.2.5 running on a MacBook Pro with 10.6.6. After a clean install of Xcode, I was getting the prompt to download symbols for 4.2.1 after plugging in my iPhone. After the transfer, I would no longer get the prompt when attaching the iPhone, but I was getting tons of "unable to read symbols" messages.

First, what did not work for me:

- Creating symbolic link to '4.2 (8C134)' with the name '4.2.1 (8C148)'
- Creating symbolic link inside directory '4.2.1 (8C148)' like there is in '4.2 (8C134)' to the ../../Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk

Both of the above caused the 'UUID mismatch' errors for several libraries. GDB would start but appear to hang.

Finally, what is currently working for me:

- % cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
- % mkdir '4.2.1 (8C148)' # if it does not exist
- % cd '4.2.1 (8C148)'
- % cp ../4.2\ \(8C134\)/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg* .
- % cp -r ../../Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk Symbols
- Attempt to run debug session for an application and watch the Console. For each warning about a UUID mismatch, remove the file indicated in the log message (I had AudioToolbox, CoreMedia, and some others)
- Stop GDB and try again, hopefully with success

At least for my application under development, everything now works fine. Hopefully, Xcode 4.0 will clear this up.