# How to display strings in Xcode debugger?

Tags: xcode, ios4, debugging, data-formatters

I always used to be able to see NSString values in the debugger, without problem. Since updating to 3.2.5 all I see is the format string `{(char *)Xcode_CFStringSummary($VAR, $ID)}:s`

I can't see anything wrong with that. Can anybody please tell me what the correct formatter should be?

Comment: I'm still struggling with this and debugging without seeing any strings. Very frustrating. Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 9):

I'm having this same problem and haven't found a solution.  But at least I did figure out you can still view the strings by right clicking on the string variable and selecting "Print Description to Console".

Comment: Thanks a lot for that tip! You having trouble too, after updating? I was surprised not to find any reference to it anywhere.

Comment: Hi Steve, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and at the same time I noticed a couple of errors about missing symbols for xcode debug libraries ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260291/issue-with-iphone-sdk-4-2-1)). Fixing the errors as described in the link also made my strings start working again. I realise you are talking about a different version of the SDK, but maybe the problem is the same.