# Unable to load symbol file and a UDID mismatch- how to fix?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, remote-debugging

I get this error in debugger and its preventing a debugging.

unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable     to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: warning: Unable     to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1    (8C148a)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message

Any things to try? Ideas?

Cheers

Comment: The answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260291/issue-with-iphone-sdk-4-2-1/4566804#4566804)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version of Xcode produced the build you're trying to debug and what iOS SDK was set as the Base SDK? What version of iOS is running on the device on which you're trying to debug the app?

This is a similar question to [UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215252/uuid-mismatch-detected-with-the-loaded-library) and my guess is that you have a mismatch between device and IDE, possibly from using a beta version of the SDK.

Comment: The only way I was able to get around this issue was by deleting the DeviceSupport files for the 4.2.1 iOS version, which can be found at:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
After deleting the files and restarting Xcode, I plugged in my device and was prompted to restore the symbol files from the device itself - it took about 5 minutes and after this, everything was back to working perfectly.

Comment: Deleting the above directory and having Xcode recreate it worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: this is the second time you've helped me. Thanks man
@sam - thanks for summing this up, i had the same problem and i was having a hell of a time trying to debug without using my phone.

Comment: I had this issue too but deleting and recreating the 4.2.1 folder did not help me. I copied the "dns.so" file from the "4.2 (8C134)/Symbols/usr/lib/info" folder to the same path in the "4.2.1 (8C148)" folder and it cleared the issue. Maybe someone with  deeper understanding of Xcode can comment if this is OK?