# Unable to Read Symbols for iOS SDK 4.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation

Everytime I attempt to debug an app on my 3GS running iOS 4.2.1 (8C148a) I get this warning in the compiler:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).
```

At first I thought this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260291/issue-with-iphone-sdk-4-2-1) might be rooted in the same cause but the accepted answer didn't work and the other answers didn't seem to apply. The exact warning is a little different and only occurs once but I believe it's the reason the crashes aren't providing any information to help me debug. Anyone else seeing this issue or have an idea of how to solve it?

EDIT: Updating with more Models and iOS version based on comments and some other tests

iPhone 3G w/iOS 4.2.1 (8C148)

iPhone 3GS w/iOS 4.2

iPod Touch 4G w/iOS 4.2.1

Comment: I just got this building (with the Xcode install profile) to the device (an iPhone 3Gs) running iOS 4.2

Comment: got the same on an iPod Touch 4G running 4.2.1

Comment: I had this issue too but deleting and recreating the 4.2.1 folder (as is suggested in some other related questions) did not help me. I copied the "dns.so" file from the "4.2 (8C134)/Symbols/usr/lib/info" folder to the same path in the "4.2.1 (8C148)" folder and it cleared the issue. Maybe someone with deeper understanding of Xcode can comment if this is OK?

Comment: EagleOfToledo, what kind of output are you getting when debugging? I would think that using the symbol file from another build would wonk up the stack traces.

Comment: I am just getting the normal output to the console, no more warnings and nothing showing in the debugger.