# warning: Unable to read symbols

Tags: iphone

When I try to run my app in iOS 4.2.1, I am getting following warning messages;

```
[Switching to thread 11523]
[Switching to thread 11523]
`/xcode iOS/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/dyld' has changed; re-reading symbols.
`/xcode iOS/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/dyld' has changed; re-reading symbols.
continue
`/xcode iOS/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/dyld' has changed; re-reading symbols.
`/xcode iOS/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/dyld' has changed; re-reading symbols.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /xcode iOS/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).
```

I don't know what is happening here.

Is there any issues, when we get this kind of warning messages ?

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue, and I have a theory that it has something to do with a jailbroken device, but I'm not entirely sure...

Comment: I tried with my iPad, I am getting the same warning messages.

Comment: FYI this QA is completely out of date for years now. For years, Xcode has been an "application-type" app.  Enjoy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure this will solve your problem: [UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215252/uuid-mismatch-detected-with-the-loaded-library)

- Johannes

Comment: Joh, I also urge you and anyone reading to check this answer from Chris Lavender: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260291/issue-with-iphone-sdk-4-2-1 , regarding the info/dns.so file.  Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Xcode and the debugger expect iOS 4.2, but your device runs iOS 4.2.1.

What you can do to avoid this error; Let Xcode gather the needed symbols from your device (you may have to delete previous ones). After this, it will work without any problem.

Comment: Connect your device, open the organizer in Xcode "Window > Organizer", select your iPad and click "collect symbols".

Comment: By deleting the previous ones, I meant something like "delete the Developer folder (or whatever), and reinstall it). It will usually ask you to collect the for debugging needed symbols from the device (I'm pretty sure that they are stored in a file somewhere in the Xcode folder, but I have no idea where exactly, and it might a bit dangerous to start deleting random files from there). When you reinstall it, use either a new folder or delete the existing one, both ways have forced the dialog for me to popup again.

Comment: @Joe: Hahaha, yeah, I did what you told me, but first I had to get drunk which took a little bit. My english sucks by the way anyway, I don't need to get drunk for that :P

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into this same issue lately when compiling an app in Xcode 4.2, so I searched for this same issue in the apple developer forums, and I found many threads specifically about this dns.so warning, and in many of these threads, Apple engineers replied and said it's ok to ignore this warning when it involves dns.so. One of them stated it would not even be used on iOS, so it can be ignored.