# I/O on the iPad - error

Tags: ios, ipad, input

I have the following button in my iPad app:

```
subject = [[UIButton alloc] init];
subject.frame = CGRectMake(710, 5, 180, 30);

[[subject layer] setCornerRadius:8.0f];
[[subject layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
[[subject layer] setBorderWidth:3.0f];
[[subject layer] setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]];
subject.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
[subject setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[subject setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
[subject addTarget:self action:@selector(subjectPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[subject setTitle:@"Subject: ?" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[subject layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]];
[self.view addSubview:subject];
```

Here is the function that gets called when I click the button:
- (void)subjectPressed {

```
UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Subject" message:@"Please enter the Subject:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.tag = 0;
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
alertTextField.placeholder = @"Enter Subject";
[alert show];
```

}

When I click the button, I get the following error:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/TextInput/Riven.bundle/Riven (file not found).
warning: No copy of Riven.bundle/Riven found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
```

What's this about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the files in the following folder:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
```

Restart Xcode and plug your iPad back in.

Another similar question:

[warning: Unable to read symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594732/warning-unable-to-read-symbols)

Comment: The device support files for the ipad are present in this folder as well. It's a legacy name.