# warning: Unable to read symbols / warning: No copy of *****

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-4

This bug is really confusing me as it only happens on 1 of the test phones I have. When loading a UIWebView in my app it starts to kick these warnings out into the console and never finishes loading the site.

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/internet/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX543GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX543GLDriver (file not found).
warning: No copy of IMGSGX543GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX543GLDriver found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
```

I have looked at a few things like [warning: Unable to read symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594732/warning-unable-to-read-symbols) but nothing has really helped me with this problem. I have done a clean build command+shift+K, but that doesn't do anything ever.

Anyone help?

The phone is an iPhone 4S on iOS 5.0.1

Comment: I have checked in the file the first warning gives and it does exist so I don't know what its talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/21383