# I am getting this following warning in my In App Purchasing code on iPhone, how can I get out of this?

Tags: ios4

warning: Unable to read symbols for /Xcode4.5/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).

Answer (score 0):

Have you Added StoreKit framework. Ref following link

[Issue with iphone sdk 4.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260291/issue-with-iphone-sdk-4-2-1)