# App doesnt build to device

Tags: iphone, xcode

When i try to build my app to device, it gets stuck on the splash screen and doesn't get past it.

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1702) (Mon Jun 20 02:29:40 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "AVFoundation" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "libSystem.B.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "libgcc_s.1.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreFoundation" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "libobjc.A.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-186-34
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
[Switching to process 11523 thread 0x0]
[Switching to process 11523 thread 0x0]
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  found).
warning: No copy of CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation (file not found).
warning: No copy of Foundation.framework/Foundation found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES (file not found).
warning: No copy of OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore (file not found).
warning: No copy of QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: No copy of VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial (file not found).
warning: No copy of DataMigration.framework/DataMigration found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X (file not found).
warning: No copy of EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
```

Here's part of the logs. It just sits on the splash screen and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the log you given, there is the warning- `Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)`

you can have a look at this thread to solve it.

[Issue with iphone sdk 4.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260291/issue-with-iphone-sdk-4-2-1)

Comment: That message is not an error, just a warning. It will not prevent code from running, it only interferes with getting debugging symbols for libraries on the device. As described by the article you linked to. If I wasn't in a good mood, I'd give you a -1.

Comment: Yes its not an error. I edited the answer. I faced the 'Unable to read symbols................' warning and the link i pasted worked for me. so i referred to that link.

Answer (score 0):

Does it compile on the simulator? After a quick google, apparently this error comes from either a bug in the SDK or memory mismanagement.

Comment: Yeah, it runs perfectly in the simulator